# Report Server SSRS Users table

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

How can i get the userID before i added roles to the user? As the users will be at UserAccounts table before you create roles for the users, it will only insert into Users table once you created the role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use username() or userprincipalname(), On which username() will return a user in the format of DOMAIN\User and userprincipalname() will return a user in the format of user@domainemail.com.

Comment: I'm not sure it answer the original question